# How to Develop Email List Application Using Javascript If-Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, if-statement

[image]

Hi,

I'm trying to develop Javascript that will get this Email form to work properly. Basically, I need to make sure that the user fills out both fields when the “Submit” button is clicked.  If the fields are not filled, an alert message should show up and the cursor should move back to that field. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
<script src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>
<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align=right bgcolor=#ffffff><img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<center>
<table width=85%>
<tr>
<td valign=top>
<form id="emailform" method="post" action="form.html">Name:<br>     
<input id="name" name="textname" size=35><br><br>E-mail:<br>
<input id = "email" name="textname" size=35><br><br>
<input type=submit name="button1" value="Submit">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

submit = function () {
  var name = $("name").value;
  var email = $("email").value;
  var isValid = true;
}

//validate entry for "Name:"
if (name == "") {
  $("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = 
  "Name is required.";
isValid = false;
} else {
$("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}

//validate entry for "E-Mail:"
if (email == "") {
$("email_error").firstChild.nodeValue = 
    "E-mail is required.";
isValid = false;
} else {
$("email_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}

if (isValid) {
//use the submit method of the form object to submit the form
$(emailform).submit();
}
```

Right now nothing is happening at all - whether the fields are filled out or not. I'm new to Javascript and am trying to learn, so please provide explanation if possible. The "firstChild node" concept is especially confusing to me. Thank you!

JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/kx1q9wo7/

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using jQuery. Are you open to jQuery solutions?

Comment: Not preferred but yes

Comment: I am not sure that code works, but try removing `var` word. However, I can provide you a better and simplest code to make the same.

Comment: Once you fix things like "include the validation code in the `submit()` function" and "actually use the `submit()` function as an `onsubmit` handler", you still don't actually have any elements with IDs `email_error` or `name_error`. You'll want to add those.

Comment: How do I include the validation code in the submit function? I understand how to add the IDs email_error and name_error.

Comment: I provided a JSfiddle link in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious you're a beginner. So please don't take this the wrong way. There is so much wrong with what you're doing is difficult to know where to start. First, you aren't using jquery, but it appears that the code you've been looking up on how to do this was primarily jQuery code. It doesn't appear that you know how to declare a function or use a function as an event handler. You don't understand variable scope. You're trying to set values on elements with the id's of 'name_error' and 'email-error' but those elements don't exist in your HTML. And besides the javascript issues, you're using table layouts for your page. Do yourself a favor and learn CSS and use div's instead of tables.

Here's a working validation (non-jQuery) of your form. I'd also recommend you learn jQuery as it is the future (actually the present) of javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ykvwxu9/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="logo-wrapper">
        <img src="castaway_logo.jpg"><br />
        Vacations, LLC
    </div>
    <div id="errors"></div>
    <form id="emailform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateEmailForm();" action="form.html">Name:<br>     
        <input id="name" name="textname" size=35><br><br>E-mail:<br>
        <input id = "email" name="textname" size=35><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#logo-wrapper {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#errors { 
    clear:both;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    color: red;
}

form#emailform { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function validateEmailForm(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var errDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
    var error = '';
    var focusElem;
    if(name.value.length == 0){
        error += "Name is required<br />";
        focusElem = name;
    }

    if(email.value.length == 0){
        error += "Email is required<br />";
        if(focusElem == undefined){
            focusElem = email;
        }
    }

    if(error.length > 0){
        errDiv.innerHTML = error;
        focusElem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't write the code for the HTML page....it's the code our teacher sent us. I understand HTML and CSS pretty well but you're right to say that I'm a total beginner at Javascript. Declaring functions, event handlers, variable scope - I'm barely familiar with these terms because our teacher hasn't taught us anything. Thank you for your explanation. I will try to work with this and get back to you.

Comment: That's why he teaches instead of doing web development. I feel somewhat bad that I've helped you cheat on your homework. But then I realized, the fact that you at least know enough to come to SO to look for answers means you're on the right track. This is where I get my best code :-)

Comment: As far as the class goes, I don't really care if I get an A or an F, I just want to learn the material. I'm a bit confused about the second if statement. Why isn't it just: 

if(name.value.length == 0){
        error += "Email is required<br />";
        focusElem = email;
    }

like the first if statement? 
What does the if(focusElem == undefined){ do?

Comment: Also not really sure about the third statement. It looks like it's saying: if the error length is greater than zero, get the "errors" div in the html and then after that I'm lost.

Comment: The "if(focusElem == undefined)" is checking to see if we've already set the focusElem to the Name element. if so we don't want to overwrite it. We want to set focus on the Name element if both are empty. Without this if both fields are empty the focus would fall to the email field. Not a terrible thing but it makes more sense for the focus to be on the first empty required field.

Comment: At the top of the function I declared a variable "var errors = ``; " This creates an empty string. The "if(error.length > 0)" checks to see if this string's length is greater than zero. If it is then we have errors. so we need to display them. errDiv.innerHTML sets the html inside the <div id="errors"> with the text we've accumulated in the 'errors' variable. Then we set the focus and return false to keep the form from submitting. If we don't have errors we return true and the form submits.

Comment: Since your teacher didn't give you a div in the html to display your errors, you may have to change the "errDiv.innerHTML = error;" to "alert(error);" and change "Name is required<br />" to "Name is required\n". this will output the errors to an alert popup. But alerts do not display html they display plain text. so the <br /> which creates a new line in html will show in an alert box. the "\n" is the plain text equivalent. it will create a new line in your alert box.

Comment: Oh okay. Yes it does. Thanks for your explanation. Lastly I need to put the alert messages just to the right of text boxes. I might have to split them up and do one at a time so that they line up perfectly. Right now they're way off to the right (see screenshot).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92422/discussion-between-user3546086-and-gregg-duncan).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `var` word in the `submit()` function. `var` tells to javascript engine that the scope of this variable is inside the function, so in another functions doesn't exists. Removing var you are attaching the variable to the global `window` object. It doesn't works in strict mode, but you don't define it so it works for you

Comment: So it would just be submit, but then var stays for name, email, and isValid?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I took out var in the submit function (in the javascript)...is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Alright lets go through a number of issues that are going to prevent your code from working..

```
var  submit = function () {
  var name = $("name").value; 
  var email = $("email").value;
  var isValid = true;

    //These are all local variables so they won't be accessible any where else. Nor are you really checking anything. This function just sets isValid = true locally.
}
```

This isn't really the proper way to define an event listener or a function. I'm not really sure what you were going for here.. If this is supposed to attach to the submit event of the form you might want to look at the `onsubmit` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

If you're just wanting a global function, you should be defining it like so:

```
function submit() { 
    //Insert code here
}
```

---

```
//validate entry for "Name:"
if (name == "") {
  $("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "Name is required.";
  isValid = false;
} else {
    $("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}
```

This isn't attached to anything, it'll run once when the script is parsed then never again.

Also it looks like `name_error` doesn't actually exist in your HTML, so that will of course not find anything.

```
//validate entry for "E-Mail:"
if (email == "") {
    $("email_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "E-mail is required.";
    isValid = false;
} else {
    $("email_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
}
```

Same here, you're just arbitrarily running this script when the script is loaded. Not actually checking for anything.

```
if (isValid) {
    //use the submit method of the form object to submit the form
    $(emailform).submit();
}
```

This code will, like the rest, run one time. Check if `isValid` is true, which it won't be because your `isValid` variable is not accessible globally. If it is magically available though it will automatically submit your form.

---

Here's a basic jsfiddle showing you how to properly attach an event handler as well as define global variables instead of variables in closures.

http://jsfiddle.net/pbu78npx/1/

It should be a good starting point for what you're wanting.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cleaner version of how you can do it:

```
$("#emailform").submit(function(e)
{
   var isValid = Validate();
   if(!isValid)
   {
       e.preventDefault();   
   }
});


function Validate()
{
    var isValid = true;
    if($.trim($("#name").val()) == "")
    {       
        isValid = false;
        $("#name_error").text("Name is required.");
    }
    else
        $("#name_error").text("");


    if($.trim($("#email").val()) == "")
    {      
        isValid = false;
        $("#email_error").text("Email is required.");
    }
    else
        $("#email_error").text("");


    return isValid;   

}

<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align=right bgcolor=#ffffff><img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<center>
<table width=85%>
<tr>
<td valign=top>
<form id="emailform" method="post" action="form.html">Name:<br> 
    <div id="name_error"></div>
<input id="name" name="textname" size=35><br><br>E-mail:<br>
<div id="email_error"></div>
<input id = "email" name="textname" size=35><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</center>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gy1oj8dz/2/

Comment: Why do we delete: 

var $ = function (id) {
 return document.getElementById(id);
}

Comment: The fact you can do $("#id") directly, you don't need another function to return its id.

Comment: Try going through the selectors in jquery : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ . It would make your life a lot better when writing client side script.